# OutputCache setting inside my asp.net mvc web application. Multiple syntax to prevent caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I am working on an asp.net MVC web application and I need to know if there are any differences when defining the OutputCache for my action methods as follow:-

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

VS

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, Location="None", VaryByParam = "*")]
```

VS

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

Will all the above three setting prevent caching the data , or each on have different meaning ?

**Second question** what is the main difference between defining `duration=0` & `NoStore=true` ? will both of them prevent caching ?
Thanks

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The `NoStore` property is used to inform proxy servers and browser that they should not store a permanent copy of the cached content by setting `Cache-Control: no-store` within the request header.

Duration simply specifies how long the content of the controller action should be cached, e.g. 10seconds. This will set the `Cache-Control: max-age` to >= 0. And also sets the `Expires` header to a valid timestamp.

To your initial question, no, the three variations do not have the same meaning.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

create a cache-header like this

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Expires: Fri, 03 Jan 2014 12:32:15 GMT
```

---

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, Location="None", VaryByParam = "*")]
```

creates the following cache-header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
```

This is basically what you want to see if you want to prevent caching by all means. VaryByParam is optional (at least in MVC5) and the default is "*" anyways, so you can simply use `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]` instead.

---

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

even creates a public cache control...

```
Cache-Control: public, no-store, max-age=0
Expires: Fri, 03 Jan 2014 12:36:38 GMT
```

There is a good post on SO which discusses the difference between [max-age=0 and no-cache etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache).

At the end all three might prevent caching your data but still have different meanings.

Comment: Removing the OutputCache will force some browsers for example IE to cache partial views automatically. that why i have defined this . so if i define NoStore=true , then there is not any meaning for the duration, is that right ??

Comment: and you mentioned that the three syntax for the Outputcache will not prevent caching ? I think they should prevent caching ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, hope my update now answers your question. And you are right, not defining any cache setting for the action will let MVC create a default "private" cache header which lets the browser eventually cache it...

Comment: It's stated correctly later, but the right syntax for the 3rd example is: Location=OutputCacheLocation.None -- you can't just use "None"