# Tempdata not being cleared when i click back arrow from another action?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I want show the alert message when the user is added. It happens smoothly but when i press the  back arrow of the browser from the another action it still shows the alert message.

```
//this is my partial view
<div class="row" id="alerts">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    @if (TempData["Success"] != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-
hidden="true">x</button>
            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h4>
            @TempData["Success"]
        </div>

    }
</div>
</div>

//this is my controller
 public ActionResult Add(CreateViewModel objCreate)
    {
        userRepo.AddUser( objCreate);

        TempData["Success"] = "User Added Successfully!";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");    
    }

//this is my view
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
            @Html.Partial("_Alerts")
            @RenderBody()
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Index method, you can disable caching by using `OutputCacheAttribute` annotation like this

```
[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // code of Index()

}
```

Comment: Thank you! it works fine but is it still the good way to do ?

Comment: @AnandShrestha that will depend on your needs but the example above will disable caching for that particular action which is what is happening when you click somewhere after being redirected to Index then and click Back button on the browser. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) is the relevant documentation and [another relevant SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895489/outputcache-setting-inside-my-asp-net-mvc-web-application-multiple-syntax-to-pr). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think reason is when you go to back on the browser, it call controller and store value for `TempData["Success"]`

Try this using following code in your controller

```
public ActionResult Add(CreateViewModel objCreate)
{
   if (!IsPostBack){
      userRepo.AddUser( objCreate);
      TempData["Success"] = "User Added Successfully!";
   }
   return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
}
```

Comment: It gives error "The name 'IsPostBack' does not exist in the current context "

Comment: add the references check this -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx